# Turning off the buzzer on NFC reader ( NFC ACR122U) in Java

Tags: java, nfc, rfid

I am using the ACR122U NFC reader in a java program that uses NFC cards. But by default the reader buzzes when it reads a card. I am trying to turn it off by without success the NFC reader documentation (found here: http://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/419/API-ACR122U-2.03.pdf )shows that you can turn off the buzzer. But I am having trouble writing a java method for it. As you can see my class already has methods that communicate with the NFC reader. But I have be unable to convert the commands shown in the documentation into a java method.

NFCcard class :

```
package dataStores;

import java.util.List;

import javax.smartcardio.Card;
import javax.smartcardio.CardChannel;
import javax.smartcardio.CardException;
import javax.smartcardio.CardTerminal;
import javax.smartcardio.CommandAPDU;
import javax.smartcardio.ResponseAPDU;
import javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory;

public class NFCcard {

    private TerminalFactory factory; 
    private List<CardTerminal> terminals;
    private CardTerminal terminal;
    private Card card ;
    public CardChannel cardChannel;


    public NFCcard() throws CardException {
        factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
        terminals = factory.terminals().list();
        terminal = terminals.get(0);
        card = terminal.connect("*");
        cardChannel = card.getBasicChannel();   
        cardChannel.transmit( new CommandAPDU(new byte[] { (byte)0xE0, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x21, (byte)0x01,(byte)0x77 }));
    }



    public String getCardID() throws CardException{
        String cardID = "";
        ResponseAPDU answer=cardChannel.transmit( new CommandAPDU(new byte[] { (byte)0xFF, (byte)0xCA, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00 }));
        byte r[] = answer.getData();
          for (int i=0; i<r.length; i++)
              cardID+=r[i];
        return cardID;
    }

}
```

Comment: when you want to turn it off? when a card is detected?

Comment: It only buzzes when the card is scanned.

Comment: you mean as soon as detected?

Comment: Yes as soon as a card is detected the buzzer goes off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this :

```
byte buzzerOn = (byte)0xFF;
byte buzzerOff = (byte)0x00;
byte clazz = (byte)0xFF;
byte ins = (byte)0x00;
byte p1 = (byte)0x52;
byte p2 = buzzerOff;
byte le = (byte)0x00;

byte[] apdu = new byte[]{clazz,ins,p1,p2,le};
ResponseAPDU answer = cardChannel.transmit( new CommandAPDU(apdu));

byte successSW1 = (byte)0x90;
byte successSW2 = (byte)0x00;
if(answer.getSW1() == successSW1 && answer.getSW2() == successSW2){
    //done
}else{
    //failed
}
```

Response must be `90 00`

Comment: Worked perfectly.Thanks

Comment: Perfect Thank YOU!