# ACR122U Reader disable beep

Tags: nfc, acs, reader, beep

I'm using the ACR122U Card reader. Is there any possibility to disable the Beep sound when placing a card on the reader?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning off the buzzer on NFC reader ( NFC ACR122U) in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535054/turning-off-the-buzzer-on-nfc-reader-nfc-acr122u-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

With C# you can use this nuget packgage: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NFC-ACR122U/
Find more infos also here for nfc: https://www.sydesoft.de

Comment: I can't find any documentation about this nuget.

Comment: here is something maybe helps you:
https://www.sydesoft.de/Techblog/nfc-reader-acr122u.html

Comment: @nxexo007: They changed the domain name for their tech blog, now it is at https://www.sydesoft-blog.de/nfc-reader-acr122u.html .